# AndroidTV Access Point

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I got an Android 9 TV Box with root access connected via LAN.
Now I want to use the WLAN as an access point/bridge with same SSID/password and after the handover the IP should stay the same.
The basic hotspot feature works but without the requirement that the IP on e.g. smartphone stays the same.

So basically I want that the Router/Gateway is the only DHCP in the network.
Is there any app or method to do this?
All devices in my network got reserved gateway IPs and I need static IPs because of my "smart" home...

Since English isn't my first language I used my paint skills and made a little picture of the situation:

[image]